# Set variable as schema

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that I want to be able to use across database schemas. Right now it is written so that I need to replace the schema in several places of the query. How do I set that up as a variable so that all I need to do is change it in one place?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@schema VARCHAR(255) = 'dbo'
SET @sql = 'SELECT *
            FROM '+@schema+'.yourTable
           '
EXEC (@sql)
```

You could use this in a cursor to loop through schema's:

```
DECLARE @Iterator varchar(255)
        ,@strSQL varchar(MAX) 
DECLARE xyz CURSOR
FOR
--Select stuff to iterate over
        SELECT name
        FROM  sys.schemas
OPEN xyz 
FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
INTO @Iterator 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--Do stuff
SET @strSQL = 'SELECT *
                FROM '+@Iterator+'.yourTable
               '
Exec (@strSQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
    INTO @Iterator 
END
CLOSE xyz 
DEALLOCATE xyz 
GO
```

To test your dynamic SQL statements, you can change `EXEC` to `PRINT` and ensure that the resulting query is as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms might be the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I have gotten pretty far with your input.  However, now I am having issues with the print statement.

Comment: set @query =
'set @B = 
(select count (*) as B  
from '+@C+'.Customer 
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CreationDate,111) = 
(select MAX (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CreationDate,111))
from '+@C+'.Customer )
)
set @A = 
(select MAX (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CreationDate,111))
from '+@C+'.Customer
print ''The last customer load for '+@C+' added '+
 @B+' customers to the '+@C+'.Customer table and occurred on  '+@A

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL. Here is an example -

```
DECLARE @Column varchar(25)
DECLARE @sqlStmt varchar(max)
SET @Column = 'MyColumn' 
SET @sqlStmt = N'SELECT ' + @Column + ' FROM MyTable'
EXEC (@sqlStmt)
```

Comment: GoatCO's answer is way better than mine. :)